# Using CRS Bipolar oblique conic conformal projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am teacher for geography in Germany. My students use in class the "Diercke Weltatlas". In this atlas there is a [Map of South an Northamerica](https://diercke.westermann.de/content/amerika-physische-%C3%BCbersicht-978-3-14-100800-5-206-1-1). As far as I can tell the projection of the map is a Bipolar oblique conic conformal projection. I would like to create an identical map (in terms of Projection) with QGIS. I already found out that the Bipolar Conique Projection is an adaption of the Lambert Conformal Conic (ESRI:102009). I also found a PDF titled [Map projections: A working manual](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395). On Page 116 there is a total chapter about the Bipolar Oblique Conic Conformal Projection and some explanations how it works.

How do I create such a map in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question for GIS SE.

Comment: In addition both your questions seek opinions i.e. how easy, how much time - both will depend on the skills and experience you bring to each task.

Comment: I think your two separate questions should be something like: "How do I create such a map in QGIS" and "How do I create my own CRS using QGIS".

Comment: QGIS uses the PROJ software which supports bipolar oblique conic. There are issues when data is too far from the area of interest, as you'll see in the documentation's picture [here](https://proj.org/operations/projections/bipc.html?highlight=bipolar#).